# Obtain Text value of selected element using cheerio

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I am trying to access the text value from a website. Instead of getting **Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope (1977)**, I get **Star Wars (1977)**. It seems like everything from the semi colon is removed automatically. Code snippet is down below:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')

const movieUrl ='https://www.imdb.com/title/';

function getMovie(imdbID){

    return fetch(`${movieUrl}${imdbID}`)
            .then(response => 
                response.text())
            .then(body =>{
                const $ = cheerio.load( body);
                const $title = $('.title_wrapper h1');
                const title = $title.text();

                console.log(title);

            })
            .catch(error =>{
                console.error(error);
            })
}


module.exports = {getMovie};
```

In my app.js file, I have the following route:

```
const scraper = require('./testscrape');

[app.get('/movie/:imdbID', (req, res)=>{
    scraper.getMovie(req.params.imdbID)
        .then(movie =>{
            res.json(movie)
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            console.error(error); 
        })
})][1]
```

The url of the webpage is found here: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076759/

Comment: IMDB shows different titles in different scenario's. Print the full page html to see which page your script is getting. It might just be different from your browser's.

Comment: It gets the page I want, what is not happening is to select the text of the title. I can get it successfully if I use the jQuery selectors on the Chrome Dev Console ( `$('.title_wrapper h1').text();`  gets the result **Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope (1977)**). But it will not get me the same result if I run the Cheerio query Selector ( `$('.title_wrapper h1').text();` gets the result **Star Wars (1977)**). Its like everything from the semicolon is chopped off.

Comment: `$("h1")` seems fine at the current time. I don't see that wrapper class any longer, so voting to close as not reproducible.